# Не происходит переход на другую сцену в Unity. Ошибок никаких не имеется!

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, firebase-database, firebase-android

Сделал в Unity проверку на наличие значения переменной userID в базе данных. Если да - то в лог выводим кол-во монеток. Если нет - выводим в лог, мол, такого юзера нет и переходим на сцену регистрации. Тут то и проблема. Никаких ошибок нет:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Database1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string userID;
    
    void Start()
    {
        userID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
       FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").Child(userID).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => { 
            if (task.IsFaulted) { 
                Debug.LogError("Error getting data from Firebase database"); 
                return; 
            } 
        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result; 
            if (snapshot.Exists) {
                if (snapshot.HasChild("coins")) { 
                    long pCoins = (long)snapshot.Child("coins").Value; 
                    Debug.Log("Value of coins: " + pCoins); 
                    // do something with pCoins variable 
                } else { 
                    Debug.Log("User does not have coins data"); 
                } 
            } else {
                Debug.Log("User does not exist in the database");
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }
});
    }
}
```

Comment: вы точно загрузили 2 сцену в билд сэтингс?

Comment: "User does not exist in the database" - этот лог появляется в логах? Что вообще появляется в логах?

Comment: Я загрузил 2 сцену в билд сэттингс.
В логе появляется сообщение "User does not exist in the database".
После появления сообщения жду долго, но ничего не происходит, перехода нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переходить по имени сцены
Используйте
SceneManager.LoadScene("ExampleScene");
Где ExampleScene - это название вашей сцены
В моём проекте была похожая ошибка, и это помогло

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]